# MASM32 program to tell if strings are different or the same

Tags: string, assembly, x86, compare, masm32

I've trying to make a code in MASM32 to tell if two strings inserted by the user are different from another and when I run it it tells that both are different, even when they aren't.

Here's my code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none


include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
    prompt db "Insert string:",0
    same_msg db "Both string are the same.",0
    diff_msg db "The strings are different.",0
    string db 50 dup(?)
    string2 db 50 dup(?)

.code

main:
    push offset prompt
    call StdOut

    push 50
    push offset string
    call StdIn

    push offset prompt
    call StdOut

    push 50
    push offset string2
    call StdIn

    call crt__stricmp
    cmp eax, 0
    je same
    jne diff

same:
    push offset same_msg
    call StdOut

diff:
    push offset diff_msg
    call StdOut

end main
```

Output:

*Insert string:123
Insert string:123
The strings are different.*

Comment: When they are the same you print out they are the same and then fall through into the code that says they are different. It also doesn't appear you passed the strings (you need to push the offset of `string1` and `string2`) to compare as parameters to `crt__stricmp` . I assume as well that  `crt__stricmp` is CDECL (C) calling convention and will need the stack restored afterwards (clean up the parameters pushed). You also seem to be missing a call to `ExitProcess` to exit the program.

Comment: A version that may work is here: https://pastebin.com/05usHtPT . A slightly cleaner version that uses INVOKE directive in MASM to deal with parameter passing, calling convention, stack cleanup etc can be found here:  https://pastebin.com/2SvpLT1C